# IOS simulator using XE5 wrapper init failed error

Tags: ios, delphi, delphi-xe5

I have been using the IOS simulator from XE5 for many weeks now, but suddenly it will no longer work. I get the error 'Wrapper init failed (null)'. The only thing that happened before the problem was I got a request to "update" from OSX. I said 'yes' and it appears XCode was updated but it does seem to work fine. PAserver starts OK.

When I went to options SDK manager and used the update local files cache I got the error
Directory does not exist: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS7.0.sdk/usr/include/

This appears to be an incompatibilty between the PAServer and Xcode 5.1 and SDK 7.1. The same happens with XE4.

The question now is can you roll back XCode with success.

I did roll back to Xcode 5.0.2 and everything appears to work OK.

Comment: Yes. Similar issue here after XCode upgrade. You might get a few more views with a generic "Delphi" tag?

Comment: The new Xcode changed from the latest beta to the final. Embarcadero is fixing the issue and would provide a hot fix ASAP.

Answer (score 0):

Roll back to Xcode 5.0.2 and Late October command line tools.  Confirmed that this allows Delphi to invoke the simulator correctly.
Make sure you set SDK to 7.0 too, 7.1 won't work.  With SDK 7.0 the compile is aimed at a usable SDK.

Answer (score 0):

xcode 5.1 contains only iOS 7.1 SDK. So this is not incompatibility between paserver, but only lack of sdk in xcode .app package. You can always open the app package (right mouse button etc) and simple copy/paste older sdks into the right subfolder inside xcode.app

The other (easier) way is to install parallel xcode 5.1 and xcode 5.0 (changing names for example as follows: xcode51.app, xcode.app (for 5.0) - simulator works even with command line tools setup to 5.1 in xcode/preferences/locations).
For updating local file cache of sdk in delphi you need to rename old version to xcode50.app and 5.1 to xcode.app (I think that a path is hardcoded in paserver). In this configuration you can add 7.1 sdk, and fix it according to: http://delphi.radsoft.com.au/2013/10/making-delphi-xe4-compile-for-ios-devices-with-xcode-5/
After updating revert xcode file names and you will be able to compile against iOS 7.1 and run in device as well as in simulator :) - checked in Delphi XE4, so I think it will work in XE5 too.